# ClickOnce manifest signing with TFS build

Tags: tfs, clickonce

I am trying to get my clickonce manifest signed using tfs build. There are many guides out there on how to do this but they seem overly complex. Can I not simply add the cert to the cert store and set sign manifest to true? Many of the guides say mage.exe is needed.. is this true?